# VBA optimisation - How much time does unnecessarily dimming objects add?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not asking for someone to spend ages going through my entire code to fully optimize it but is there anything glaringly obvious/inefficient in the below code? I have managed to get the run time from 5 minutes down to 2 minutes by opening the csv's as text `OpenText`, are there any other tips and tricks like that?

I dim wb1 multiple times when I only need to do it once, how much time if any would that add?

Essentially the below code loops through csv files in a directory, copies data out of the tabs if they meet validation rules before moving the file.

```
Sub CopyCSVs()

Dim fileName As Variant
Folder = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\loc\"
fileName = Dir("C:\Users\username\Desktop\loc\*csv")
Dim n As Integer
Dim s As String
Dim FSO As Object
Dim destFolder As String
destFolder = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\loc\Added to DB\"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
n = FreeFile()
Open "C:\Users\username\Desktop\loc\UploadLog.txt" For Output As #n
    
While fileName <> ""

   Workbooks.OpenText Folder & fileName, Local:=True
   Workbooks("eMBcsv.xlsm").Activate
   Dim wb1 As Workbook
   Dim wb2 As Workbook
   Dim lcHeading(100) As Variant
   Dim wsht As Worksheet

On Error GoTo Err1
    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Call newSht
    Set wsht = wb1.ActiveSheet
    
    For f = 1 To Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Column
        lcHeading(f) = Cells(1, f)
    Next f


    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
    Z = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    s = vbNewLine & Now() & " " & Z
    Print #n, s

    For f = 1 To 100

        wb2.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find(lcHeading(f), After:=ActiveCell).Activate

        If f = 1 And Application.CountA(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow) = 0 Then
            Range("A3:A10000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
        End If

        g = ActiveCell.Column
        h = ActiveCell.Row

        If f = 1 Then
            i = Cells(h, g).End(xlDown).Row
            q = "Max date is " & CDate(Application.Max(Range(Cells(h + 1, g), Cells(i, g))))
            w = "Min date is " & CDate(Application.Min(Range(Cells(h + 1, g), Cells(i, g))))
            p = DateDiff("m", CDate(Application.Min(Range(Cells(h + 1, g), Cells(i, g)))), 
            CDate(Application.Max(Range(Cells(h + 1, g), Cells(i, g)))))
            s = q & " " & w & vbNewLine & p & " months"
            Print #n, s
        End If

        Range(Cells(h + 1, g), Cells(i, g)).Copy _
        wb1.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, f)

        If lcHeading(f) = "" Then Exit For


    Next f

Err1:
    s = f & " columns imported"
    '& vbNewLine & "Runtime error detected " & Err.Description
    Print #n, s
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    FSO.MoveFile Source:=Folder & Z, Destination:=destFolder & Z
    fileName = Dir
Wend

Close #n

End Sub

Sub newSht()

If Cells(2, 1) <> "" Then
   Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)).Copy
   Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
   ActiveSheet.Paste
End If

End Sub
```

Edit: I just made some changes to the code, moved the first loop and the dim's at the start of the while (to outside the loop) and managed to shave 2 seconds off the run time.
Makes me wonder if anything more can be done and whether it would even be worth it? In an ideal world I would want it under 60 seconds but there's no point making changes just to make it two seconds faster.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time it takes, is basically determined by the amount of times you reference a COM object (sheet, range, cell, etc). To make your code run faster, I would copy all the data you need from the source sheet into one big array, then modify the array (possibly by moving data to another array), then write the data from the resulting array to the destination sheet. See [VBA speed up For loop with array/dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68912994/vba-speed-up-for-loop-with-array-dictionary/68947199#68947199)

To make your function run faster, limit the amount of references to COM objects and operate on an array instead. Example:

```
Sub CopyCSVs()
    Dim Lst As Variant, Lst2 As Variant
    ...            
    While fileName <> ""
        Lst = wb2.ActiveSheet.UsedRange ' Move this outside the loop if possible.
        ReDim Lst2(1 To NumRows, 1 To NumColumns)
        For f = 1 To 100
           ' Modify Lst or copy data to a new array Lst2
           ' Do not reference any sheets or cells here.
        Next f
        ' Copy the data in Lst or Lst2 to another sheet/workbook, e.g:
        Wb1.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(Lst2), UBound(Lst2, 2)) = Lst2
        ' You do not need to activate the sheet you copy data to, when
        ' doing it this way.
    Wend
    ...
End Sub
```

Here are some other observations:

- Creating new files might take a long time, depending on your setup (antivirus, etc). Test it by only creating the new workbooks, and nothing else.
- Keep your Dim's together, at the top of the method. I have seen VBA produce weird bugs, when you mix Dim's with other statements.
- Avoid the use of copy and paste, as it might cause the user to lose the data in his copy-paste buffer.
- Avoid the use of Activate on ranges. Instead use *Set Rng = wb2.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find(lcHeading(f), After:=ActiveCell)* and use the range you get. Activating a range, may interfere with what the user already selected.

Comment: Just to clarify, the Dim statements shouldn't take any time, compared to the points raised.