# How to cut down VBA the runtime of a range search from a filtered sheet inputing data into a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, range, filtering

I need to iterate through 1000 to 3000 rows in one workbook (workbook A) and find the unique row in a different workbook (workbook B) if it exists then take some information from Workbook B and enter it in workbook A. My code is taking hours.

Workbook B has 80000 to 100000 rows, but can be filtered ahead of time to show only the 800 to 3000 rows needed. I thought maybe the large file was causing the problem. Searching using xlcelltypevisible seemed like the problem, so I even tried copying the filtered data in Workbook B and pasting it into a new workbook , using that as Workbook B instead, and ceased using xlcelltypevisible. But the code is still taking hours to iterate. See code below

```
Sub Wb_to_APT()

    Dim openedWb As Workbook, APTex As Workbook
    Dim MainView As Worksheet, dis As Worksheet
    Dim disFilter As Range, filterow As Range, rng As Range, subrng As Range
    Dim countryCol1, countryCol2, SKUcol1, SKUcol2, fCol, disFCol, r As Long
    Dim i As Integer


' Must use the APT MainView export to run the macro
    Set MainView = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet


' Tells the user to open the dis file they want to copy from
    Set openedWb = openDataFile
    Set dis = openedWb.Worksheets("DIS")

' Find the last row of the APT export and dis, and fix dynamic column indices
    With dis
        countryCol1 = Application.Match("Territory", MainView.Rows(1), 0)
        countryCol2 = Application.Match("TERRITORY", .Rows(1), 0) + 1
        SKUcol1 = Application.Match("StyleColor", MainView.Rows(1), 0)
        SKUcol2 = Application.Match("PROD_CD", .Rows(1), 0)
        fCol = Application.Match("UFlow1", MainView.Rows(1), 0)
        disFCol = Application.Match("UF1", .Rows(1), 0)
        r = MainView.Cells(Rows.Count, SKUcol1).End(xlUp).Row
        'r_end = .Cells(Rows.Count, SKUcol2).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, SKUcol2), .Cells(.Cells(Rows.Count, SKUcol2).End(xlUp).Row, SKUcol2))
        Set subrng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With
    
' Iterate through Main View export to find same country-SKU in dis
    With dis
        For i = 2 To r
        ' only check filtered rows in dis
            For Each disFilter In subrng.areas
        ' match countries and SKUs
                If .Cells(disFilter.Row, countryCol2).Value2 = MainView.Cells(i, countryCol1).Value2 And _
                .Cells(disFilter.Row, SKUcol2).Value2 = MainView.Cells(i, SKUcol1).Value2 Then
                    MainView.Cells(i, fCol) = .Cells(disFilter.Row, disFCol).Value2
                    MainView.Cells(i, fCol + 1) = .Cells(disFilter.Row, disFCol + 1).Value2
                    MainView.Cells(i, fCol + 2) = .Cells(disFilter.Row, disFCol + 2).Value2
                    Exit For
                Else
                    MainView.Cells(i, fCol) = "NOT FOUND OR FILTERED OUT"
                End If
            Next disFilter
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

After trying to use a condensed workbook without filters I switched subrng.areas to just rng in the `for each disFilter` loop

Comment: Store you data in array and loop through the array. Usually much faster than looping through the sheet. [VBA speed up For loop with array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68912994/vba-speed-up-for-loop-with-array)

Comment: Two questions: 1) In the "DIS" sheet, do several "PROD_CD" correspond to one "TERRITORY" or several "TERRITORY" to one "PROD_CD" ?
2) Is your data sorted in the "DIS" sheet according to the above relationship? If not, would you mind classifying them?

Comment: Another approach would be to search the records with SQL, since for each row in the MainView there can only be one in the "DIS" sheet that meets the criteria. MainView would also need a "ROWID" column that would have the row number ( =Row() ). If you would be interested in such a solution, reply to me so we can clarify the details.

Comment: @ΑΓΡΙΑΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ the DIS sheet has both. Multiple Territories can have the same prod_cd and multiple prod_cd belong to each territory. The unique identifier for each row is territory AND prod_cd. Is that what you mean by classifying them?
MainView currently has a sequence ID, but it is not the ROWID, it's used for a third workbook not needed for the process in this post. Yes, I would be interested, so let me know what I can clarify. Ty.

Comment: @Wizhi can you give a bit more detail on which lines loop through the sheet? Your link has an example with one array, but I am looping through two ranges in separate workbooks. So would I need two arrays? And to create an array from the DIS sheet, I would need to store only visible cells, so wouldn't that slow things down quite a bit as well?

Comment: @user75667, I will need: a) A column headed "ROWNUMS" in the first book and type "=Row()" in each row b) The names of the headings in DIS, from which you copy the values. c) The areas of the columns, e.g. A1:J1 for book A and A1:F1 for book B. d) The full path with name of the second book e) The rule must apply: for each entry in book A there is only one in B that have a common key. (regardless of whether it is hidden or not), otherwise I will not get a correct result.

Comment: A quick way to store the visible cells from the DIS sheet, would be to copy paste the visible rows in a new sheet, put those rows in an array and work from there. Or take the entire sheet to an array with one column to a range variable where you loop through and check whether it's visible or not and then filter the array into a different array.